# Can I configure netflow on router other than Cisco

Tags: configuration, cisco

I am quite confused about netflow protocol. First thing I want to know is can I configure netflow on other router. We have Jflow for Juniper but what about other vendors.

Also, suppose if netflow and jflow are configured on two routers then can nfcad listen to both of them simultaneously ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Netflow and jFlow have an interesting relationship. Cisco developed NetFlow specifically for their own product, then a standards body got together and developed sFlow. While sFlow is intended to be the vendor neutral implementation of NetFlow, during the process and intervening years, enough got changed so that while they both serve the same function the protocols are not compatible.

I can't really help you configure the flow exporting, although it's documented exceptionally well on the Internet and somewhat well in the `nfdump` documentation itself. I do, however, have some good experience with the flow collection itself.

The daemons `sfcapd` and `nfcapd` are shipped as part of the [nfdump](http://nfdump.sourceforge.net/). They are used the same way and accept the same configuration parameters but where `nfcapd` is used for collecting and storing NetFlow logs `sfcapd` is used for collecting and storing sFlow logs. The Juniper jFlow is an offshoot of sFlow and is almost completely compatible with it, as such you can use the `sfcapd` process to collect those logs.

Since, you must use two separate daemons to collect the different log sources, you will also need to have them run on two different ports. This should be fairly easy to do since they are different processes with different executables.

Also keep in mind that both `nfcapd` and `sfcapd` assume they completely manage the directory structure under which the logs are stored. That means they create files and directories as needed as well as maintain their own built in log retention processor. So you define your retention schedule (in days, years, bytes, & of disk) and whenever the daemon closes out a log file it will automagically delete logs in accordance with your schedule. To do this the daemon also locks the entire directory. That is, if you tell `nfcapd` to save logs in `/opt/netflows` then a lock file gets dropped and `sfcapd` will not use that directory. So if you run both you must have them save into different locations.

Comment: Thanks man. Although, I asked this question about a month back, I am still alive at it. So, what I understand is sfcapd and nfcapd can help me cater to Cisco and Juniper routers respectively. Do we have any provision of netflow on other vendors ? Also am Important doubt I have is, wiki says cisco has defined netflow as unidirectional. I am confused here, does it mean that only request packets will be captured ? (I am where dst port is < 1024, can src port ever be a standard port. I assume it be be.)

Comment: @Ajit: Remember, sfcapd is for sFlow, so you can use it to collect exports from any vendor that implements that standard. If they do something weird you're kind of on your own. I only have experience with flow-tools, nfdump, and argus. The unidirectional thing is a bit of an annoyance. Any bidirectional connection, like say an HTTP GET, will show up in netflow as two records where the traffic from client to server is in one record and the traffic from server to client is in another.

Comment: I think that clears it out. Actually I have not yet got access to the routers and we are developing something related to it, hence so many doubts. Anyways it was nice explanation by you. Thanks.

Comment: @Ajit: No worries, I can certainly understand. I collect flows for monitoring and forensics but leave the actual network management and configuration to the network guys.

Answer (score 0):

> I am quite confused about netflow protocol. First thing I want to know
>   is can I configure netflow on other router. We have Jflow for Juniper
>   but what about other vendors.

Netflow is developed by Cisco and it supports many platforms. You can refer to [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NetFlow#NetFlow_support) to know what platform is supported.

> Also, suppose if netflow and jflow are configured on two routers then
>   can nfcad listen to both of them simultaneously ?

I have never done it before, but I think the answer is yes.

Comment: HI Gnouc, thanks for the link shared by you. It will certainly help me. I also think that nfcapd would listen to both of them I was not quite sure. Do have any info about the similarity between packets sent be nfcapd and jflow ?

Comment: One more thing I want to know is, what all details are provided in ifIndex. I mean can I come to know the exact link for which a packet is processed. I mean I want the router name and Interface IP (src,dst). Is it provided in IfIndex ?

Comment: If you use cisco netflow, try this: http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/switches/datacenter/nexus1000/sw/4_0/troubleshooting/configuration/guide/trouble_11netflow.html